# Get user location in Golang

Tags: api, google-maps, go

I'm using the `google-maps-services-go` package, which can be found [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go).

The documentation says that the GeolocationRequest fields are optional, so I left the struct empty for now.

---

**Code:**

```
c, erreur := maps.NewClient(maps.WithAPIKey("API-KEY"))
if erreur != nil {
    log.Fatalf("fatal error: %s", erreur)
}
mapReq := &maps.GeolocationRequest{}
respons, errr := c.Geolocate(context.Background(), mapReq)
fmt.Println(respons, errr)
```

---

The error I get:

```
<nil> Requested entity was not found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you set `ConsiderIP:true`  in `GeolocationRequest`?

Comment: What were you expecting? If the request has all zero values, what location should be returned?

Comment: i set it to true but same result

Comment: well you need to give it some data to work with, so try supplying one or more fields in the `GeoLocationRequest`